# Why were so many female members of Hapsburg family named Maria something?

Tags: 18th-century, names, austria, holy-roman-empire, habsburg

Recently, I have noticed that Empress Maria Theresa’s daughters’ names all begin with Maria.

- Archduchess Maria Elisabeth
- Archduchess Maria Anna
- Archduchess Maria Carolina
- Maria Christina, Duchess of Teschen
- Archduchess Maria Elisabeth
- Maria Amalia, Duchess of Parma
- Archduchess Maria Johanna Gabriela
- Archduchess Maria Josepha
- Maria Carolina, Queen of Naples and Sicily
- Maria Antonia, Queen of France

And then the empress had 2 younger sisters: Maria anna and Maria Amalia.
Joseph II, the empress’ son and heir, also had two daughters: Maria Theresa and Maria Christina.
Leopold II, another son, named all of his daughters Maria something.

The empress’s grandfather, Leopald I, the Holy Roman emperor also named all his daughters Maria something.

Is it a tradition of the 18th century to name archduchess maria something? Or is it just a Hapsburg thing?—like protruding jaw?  Why is that? And also why Maria something—not Theresa something or Elizabeth something or whatsoever? I know Maria is a common name but still, why?

Comment: It was also very common to name a child after an ancestor. See all the Louises in France and Alfonsos in Spain.

Comment: Welcome to History:Stack Exchange. Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like many other stacks, we expect questions to [provide evidence of prior research](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3227/1599). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done. Our [help], and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions.

Comment: @NotMaria SomthingK     You wote:  Is it a tradition of the 18th century to name archduchess maria something? Or is it just a Hapsburg thing?—like protruding jaw?"  You seem to think that there were any other archduchesses except for Habsburgs, which is inaccurate.  Almost every single archduke and archduchess ever was a Habsburg.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archduke

Comment: I understand that in Catholic Europe, it was common to give  both girls and boys Maria/Marie, as a first or additional name, given the Catholic theology surrounding Mary the Mother of Jesus. The German officer pivotal in the 20th July attempt on Hitler's life was Claus Philipp **Maria** Schenk Graf von Stauffenberg.

Answer (score 15):

Because they are Catholic. No other reason. Doesn't matter if you are a boy or girl. It's very common practise to give children many baptismal names, including Maria. To both girls and boys. Perhaps not today, but when I was baptized 60 years ago, it definitely was.

My parents 'blessed' me with that name too. Being a boy, and attending a non-Catholic school, I wasn't particularly happy with it. (We are in no way related to the Habsburgs!)

It is - or was - a Catholic custom. Not related to Germany or Eastern Europe. I grew up in The Netherlands where this was practised too.

With regard to the Habsburgs, it was very likely also family tradition. Especially as it was a first name for girls.

Comment: In Germany today, especially the catholic regions it is not uncommon to have „Maria“ as a second name even today. It‘s not as common as it was but still not unusual. I suspect it’s the same for Austria and Switzerland aa well.

Comment: Well ... also pretty much every family has a name they like to reuse. There's an unwritten rule in mine that at least one female in every nuclear unit has to have a first or middle name of Elisabeth (after my grandmother, who raised 5 young children alone in the 1950's after her husband died in a plane crash). That's added up now to 6 living Elisabeth's. Its not at all weird that in a Catholic family like theirs, "Maria" might serve as the name in question.

Comment: In my ex wife's culture, _all_ girls are named Maria.  They are distinguished by their middle names.

Comment: I guess this is the right answer. Sources?

Comment: Just like Muslim boys nearly all being called Mohammed.

Comment: @bonzo-lz I was 'waterboarded' (baptized) when I was a couple of days old, and raised in a very strict RC family. So: experience. :-)

Comment: At school, I always had about 5  Marias at my class (of ~35 people, half boys). Mostly, they would have a second given name to differentiate them. A little more if you count the Marianas and Ana Marias (Ana first), and the random ones such as Frederica Maria.

Comment: Karl von Habsburg, the current head of the house, has given names Karl Thomas Robert Maria Franziskus Georg Bahnam, according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karl_von_Habsburg.

Comment: Not just Catholics, but European Christians in general. My mother was Maria Magdalena, her mother was also Maria something or other, my other grandmother was xxx Maria, etc. etc.